# Change [ for ( with cite package

Tags: bibliographies, packages, citing, cite-package

Is there an option with the package cite to change the display of a citation from

[John and Mary 2014]

to

```
(John and Mary 2014)
```

?

I found this pdf with some options about the package but nothing related to the parenthesis.

Comment: It's impossible to sensibly answer to this question, because too many details are missing. ***What*** citation system are you adding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes: Provide the instructions

```
\renewcommand\citeleft{(}
\renewcommand\citeright{)}
```

after loading the `cite` citation management package. For more information, see page 4 of the package's user guide.

I can't help but observe that there seems to be something odd about your example. The `cite` package is geared to numeric-style rather than authoryear-style citation call-outs. The call-out "(John and Mary 2014)" will thus *not* be produced if you use the `cite` package. Were you maybe thinking of using the `natbib` citation management package? If so, you should load `natbib` with the option `round`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using natbib, the option [round] sets the parentheses when you load the package. Try:

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
```

There are some other useful options too. See e.g. [here](http://gking.harvard.edu/files/natnotes2.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I Just found the answer in this other pdf

http://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/~hellmund/LaTeX/bibtex2.pdf

Just redefine the commands for left and right closures:

```
\renewcommand\citeleft{(}
\renewcommand\citeright{)}
```